# Why not import a package to declare arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, import

Why don't we need to import any package to declare and use arrays in java? Since Array class is not present in java.lang so why don't we explicitly import java.lang.reflect.Array? Or is it there by default as well?

Comment: Array types aren't directly related to `Arrays`. They're simply provided by the language syntax. You don't *have* to import *anything*, it's just a shortcut to writing `foo.bar.baz.Quux quux;`.

Comment: I read that Array and Arrays are two different classes. Array calls static methods to create and use array objects. While Arrays class is used to manipulate array objects. But why don't we import Array class then

Comment: You don't need to import anything to use `int`, `double` etc either. They're just part of the language, rather than the API, so it doesn't need to be imported.

Comment: int double are primitive types while Array isn't a primitive type, like even String is a reference type and is present in java.lang which is imported by default so we don't import it explicitly. But that's not the case with Array

Comment: `Array` and `Arrays` are two separate classes, but they are just classes that happen to be *named* "array" that work with the concept of arrays. Actual array types are `int[].class`, `URL[].class`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are part of the core language. You don't need to import them for the same reason you don't need to import `int` or `float`.

The package `java.lang.reflect.Array` isn't the package for arrays, it's something else - a package for array-related [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) tools.

Comment: Java docs say that java.lang.reflect.Array contains static methods that are used to create and access array objects

Comment: Also String is part of java.Lang so it would be imported by default is int is a primitive data type so it is a part of core language

Comment: That's correct. But that's for dynamically creating arrays of types known only during runtime. That's why the methods there take a `Class<?>` argument. It's for fairly advanced usage. If you're interested in that, read about java reflection.

Comment: You're right about `String` that was a bad example on my part.

Comment: So does that mean that String and Array don't work in a similar way? Like declaring String needs a package and declaring an array doesn't? Sorry but I'm still a bit confused on this

Comment: It's fine. String is indeed *a class* in `java.lang`. But `int`, `float` as well as `int[]`, `float[]` etc aren't simple java classes. There's no `int` *class*. Arrays aren't objects of type `Array`, they're built-in types like `int`. The `Arrays` class that you have found is a utility class for advanced usage.

Comment: Right, but why is it said that arrays are objects in Java? Since they aren't using any class and are built-in types

Comment: You're right about this being a bit confusing. Arrays are strange creatures in Java. What's meant by "Arrays are objects in Java" is that arrays have methods, such as `length` and `toString()` (which sucks). But it's still a built-in type. You won't find a simple Java class that implements `int[]`.

Comment: Makes sense. I was comparing array with String class. Will read up more on it. Thank you for helping.